# I got below error when impliment GCM

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

i have try to implement GCM in android studio got below error in my logcat.

**LogCat:**

> onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION   GCM
>   IntentService class: com.project.GCMIntentService   Acquiring wakelock

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.project">

        <permission
            android:name="com.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" ></uses-permission>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

        <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->

        <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <application
            android:name="com.project.App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/FullScreenThemes">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.project.core.account.ManageAccounts" />
            <activity android:name=".projectActivity"/>
            <activity android:name=".projectLogin"/>

            <activity android:name="fieldatom.controls.SearchableItemActivity" />
            <activity android:name="com.project.SettingsActivity" />
            <activity
                android:name="com.project.core.account.AppIntro"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
            <activity
                android:name=".base.addons.mail.widget.MailDetailDialog"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
            <activity
                android:name=".base.addons.mail.widget.MailChatterCompose"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
            <activity
                android:name=".core.account.FieldAtomAccountQuickManage"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
            <activity android:name="com.project.core.account.About" />
            <activity android:name="com.project.core.account.Profile" />

            <!-- Reminder Receivers// -->
            <receiver android:name="com.project.core.utils.reminder.ReminderReceiver" />
            <receiver android:name="com.project.core.utils.reminder.ReminderActionReceiver" />


            <!--<receiver android:name=".server.notifications.OdooServerNotificationReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.project.odoo.mobile.SERVER_NOTIFICATION" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>-->

            <service android:name="com.project.core.auth.OdooAuthService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                    android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
            </service>

            <provider
                android:name="com.project.core.orm.provider.BaseModelProvider"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content"
                android:multiprocess="true" />
            <provider
                android:name="com.project.base.addons.ir.providers.IrModelProvider"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.ir_model"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <!-- Sync Customer Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name="com.project.addons.customers.providers.CustomersSyncProvider"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.res_partner"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_customers"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name="com.project.addons.customers.services.CustomerSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_customer">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/customer_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync Request Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name="com.project.addons.requests.providers.RequestSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.fa_service_request"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_request"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name="com.project.addons.requests.services.RequestSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_request">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/request_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync Stage Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name="com.project.addons.stages.providers.StageSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.fa_service_stage"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_stages"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name="com.project.addons.stages.services.StageSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_stage">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/stage_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync Account Analytic Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name="com.project.addons.accountanalytics.providers.AccountAnalyticSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.account_analytic_line"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_accountAnalytic"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name="com.project.addons.accountanalytics.services.AccountAnalyticSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_account_analytic">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/account_analytic_sync_adapter" />
            </service>



            <!-- Sync Product Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name=".addons.products.providers.ProductsSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.product_product"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_product"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name=".addons.products.service.ProductsSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_account_analytic">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/product_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync QUOTATION Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name=".addons.quotes.providers.QuotationSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.sale_order"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_quotation"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name=".addons.quotes.services.QuotationSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_quotation">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/quote_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync QUOTATIONLine Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name=".addons.quotes.providers.QuotationLineSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.sale_order_line"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_quotation_line"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name=".addons.quotes.services.QuotationLineSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_quotation_line">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/quote_line_sync_adapter" />
            </service>




            <!-- Sync Attachment Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name=".addons.attachment.providers.IrAttachmentSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.ir_attachment"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_attachment"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name=".addons.attachment.service.IrAttachmentSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_attachment">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/attachment_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync MailMessage Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name=".base.addons.mail.providers.MailMessageSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.mail_message"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_mail_message"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name=".base.addons.mail.service.MailMessageSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_mail_message">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/mail_message_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <!-- Sync Maps Provider & Service  // -->
            <provider
                android:name=".addons.maps.providers.MapsSyncProviders"
                android:authorities="com.project.core.provider.content.sync.fa_map"
                android:label="@string/sync_label_map_message"
                android:multiprocess="true" />

            <service
                android:name=".addons.maps.service.MapsSyncService"
                android:exported="true"
                android:process=":sync_map">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                    android:resource="@xml/maps_sync_adapter" />
            </service>


            <service android:name=".addons.requests.services.TimeUpdateService"></service>


            <activity
                android:name="com.project.addons.customers.CustomerDetailActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />

            <activity
                android:name=".addons.requests.utils.RequestTabDetailAcitivty"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"

                />
            <activity
                android:name=".addons.accountanalytics.VisitDetailActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />

            <activity
                android:name=".addons.accountanalytics.CreateVisitActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".addons.requests.AddPartActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".addons.requests.AddNoteActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".addons.requests.AddQuoteActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".addons.requests.utils.CaptureSignature"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".addons.requests.utils.ProductRequestListActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".addons.quotes.QuoteDetailActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".addons.products.ProductDetails"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
            <!-- Map Related Metadata -->

            <uses-library
                android:name="com.google.android.maps"
                android:required="false" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyCpjJtPYoeVN2dGqCVMCDEoR847OEwzgME" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <!-- Push Notification -->
            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>

                    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                    <category android:name="com.project" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"></service>

        </application>
        <!--CB:A6:E7:26:97:08:37:4A:D6:60:1B:9B:2C:D0:9A:3B:9F:DF:02:D3;com.project-->
    </manifest>
```

This is my project structure details below.

```
com.projcet
    App.java
    ProjcetLogin.java
    GCMIntentService.java
```

Comment: there is sample  @ https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start. You can download the sample from github and look at the code.

Comment: @Raghunandan i have check developer link and implement code in android studio and  i got this result RegIntentService﹕ GCM Registration Token: fD2hkRWz970:APA91b....but i have no idea how to communicate with my server url

Comment: Make a http post to your server. Store server api key on server

Comment: @Raghunandan i have try to everything but i am not succeed, please tell how to make http post for server side or any link...please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code working perfect in eclipse & android studio...finally i can do it.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    //Notification Constant
    Context context;
    Button btn_GCMRegister, btn_Post;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    public static String URL = "192.168.1.39:12069";
    String regId;


    public final String GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "your project id";

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        btn_GCMRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gcm_register);
        btn_GCMRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_Post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post_on_server);
        btn_Post.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_gcm_register:
                registerGCM();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_post_on_server:
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("regId", regId);
                params.put("user_id", 1);
                String server_url = URL;
                try {
                    post(server_url, params);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    /*
     *  Issue a POST request to the server.
     */
    private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, Object> params)
            throws IOException {

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(endpoint);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
        }

        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();

        // constructs the POST body using the parameters
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Object> param = iterator.next();
            bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                    .append(param.getValue());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                bodyBuilder.append('&');
            }
        }

        String body = bodyBuilder.toString();

        //Log.v(Config.TAG, "Posting '" + body + "' to " + url);

        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            Log.e("URL", "> " + url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            // post the request
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();
            // handle the response
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Json Data--->" + status);

            // If response is not success
            if (status != 200) {

                throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    private void registerGCM() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regId = gcm.register(GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                    Log.d("Reg Id----->", "" + regId);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Register Key from server : " +regId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Error: " + msg);
                }
                Log.d("MainActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Registered On GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

GCMIntentService.java

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {


    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onError", "gcm...error");
    }

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("your project id");
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] getSenderIds(Context context) {

        return super.getSenderIds(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
            String title = intent.getExtras().getString("title");
            String ticker = intent.getExtras().getString("ticker");
            generateNotification(context,message,title,ticker);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onRegistered", "gcm Registered");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("onUnregistered", "gcm...Unregistered...");
    }

    /**
     * Create a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message,String title,String ticker) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);     
        builder.setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                icon))
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentIntent(intent).setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(ticker)
                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 100)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE).setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xxx.gcmnotification" >

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.xxx.gcmnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.xxx.gcmnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.xxx.gcmnotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gcm_register"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:text="Register On GCM Server" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_post_on_server"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:text="Post On Server" />

</LinearLayout>
```